# How to compute a radius of convergence?

Tags: calculus, power-series

Suppose that i have a power series defined by
$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nz^n\\
a_0&=0\\
a_1&=1\\
a_n&=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}{3}
\end{align}$$
How i can find the convergence radius of $f$

Comment: I think the series converges for $|z|<1$.