# Finding $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ for a recursively defined sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_{n}=\frac13(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}a_{n-2})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, power-series

**Question.**

> Let $(a_n)$ be a complex sequence defined recursively:
> $$
> a_0 = 0,\quad  a_1=1, \quad a_{n}=\frac13(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}a_{n-2})\quad (n>1)
> $$
> What is $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$?

**Remarks.**

This question is motivated by [an unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1104851/) on the site that I am not able to solve. By the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), the problem of finding the radius of convergence for the power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ reduces to the limit problem above. One can probably find some other way to figure out the radius of convergence, but I would like to focus on Cauchy-Hadamard and thus particularly the limit in the question.

One straightforward attempt is to find a *closed-form* formula for the sequence so that one may able to apply asymptotic techniques to analyze $|a_n|^{1/n}$. While there are systematic ways to handle the [linear recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), I don't know how to handle this particular nonlinear case. The usual idea of "linearizing the nonlinear problem" seems not helpful here.

With help of the short Python script, I plotted the sequence $(|a_n|^{1/n})$. The result seems to suggest that the limit is $1$.

[image]

Comment: one can easily show by induction that $a_n \le \frac{20}{19}(\frac{19}{20})^n$ (enough to check it for $n=1,2,3$ as it6 then follows for $n \ge 4$ by substitution) which shows that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}a_n^{1/n} \le 19/20$ and then @Oliver comment should give the radius as the bigger root of $3x^2-x-1=0$

Comment: @Conrad: Interesting. How do you figure out the magic dominant geometric sequence? Particularly, where are the numbers $20/19$ and $19/20$ from?

Comment: If you think a little, you realize that something like $a_n \le Kc^n$ may work as long as $c<1, 3c^2-c-1>0$ and $c$ close enough to $1$ as the product decreases much faster and then since $a_1=1, K=1/c$ is natural and I tried first $9/10$ but that required $n \ge 7$ for the inequality to go by substitution (as it comes down to smallest $n$ for which $3c^2 \ge 1+c+Kc^{n-1}$, so one has to check the first cases...) while the next simple fraction $19/20$ worked from $n \ge 5$ and there the check is easy

Comment: It's actually $3c^2 \ge 1+c+Kc^{n+1}$ for $a_m \le Kc^m, m \le n$ to imply $a_{n+1} \le Kc^{n+1}$; so for $c=19/20, K=20/19$ one needs $.7575 \ge .95^n$ so actually I was a bit wrong and one needs $n \ge 6$ but still it works easily...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac13\Big(1+\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n-1}}+a_{n-2}\Big)$$

Show that $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ and deduce that $x_n:=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$ converges to some $x>0$ satisfying
$$x=\frac{1}{3}\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)$$

---

Recall that
$$\liminf_n\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq\liminf_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq\limsup_n\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$$

---

Another approach, is to consider the discrete dynamical system on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given as
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{x}_{n+1}&=G(\boldsymbol{x}_n)\\
\boldsymbol{x}_0 &= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where
$$
G(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\
\frac13 & \frac13
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y
\end{pmatrix}
+ \frac13\begin{pmatrix}  0\\ xy \end{pmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalues of the linear part of $G$ around the critical point $\boldsymbol{x}^*=[0\;0]^\intercal$ are $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{13}}{6}$.

From this, one can show that with initial conditions *closed* enough to $\boldsymbol{x}^*$, $\boldsymbol{x}_n$ converges to $\boldsymbol{x^*}$ exponentially fast (the *rate* of convergence being $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{6}$ which is happened to be $\lim_n\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ where
$\boldsymbol{x}_n:=[a_{n-1}\,a_n]^\intercal $.

Comment: Thanks. If the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$ exists, then it must be zero by the recurence. It is easy to see it is bounded from below. So being (eventually) decreasing would be sufficient. I don't see a natural way to show $a_{n+1}\le a_n$ for sufficiently large $n$.  How would you show that the limit exists?

Comment: @ripples: there are several ways to do it. For example, you can follow Conrad's suggestion (use induction) to show that $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. Also, (again induction) you can show that $0<a_n<a_4=\frac59$ for all $n>4$ and that $a_n$ is decreasing for $n\geq 5$ and that $a_n<a_4 a_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 5$.

Comment: I got the $a_n\to0$ part. Thanks again. How do you show that $(x_n)$ is convergent?

Comment: Notice that $x_n$ is closed to satisfying the sequence $y_n$ that satisfies $y_{n+1}=\frac13(1+\frac{1}{y_n})$ and that for $n\geq 7$, $x_n<\frac89$. The sequence $y_n$ with $y_{n_0}>1$ can be easily shown to converge.

Comment: I don't follow why $y_n$ can be easily shown to converge. Could you elaborate? I also do see that how the convergence of $y_n$ implies that of $x_n$.

Comment: $y_n=f(y_{n-1})$ where $f(y)=\frac13\Big(1+\frac1y\Big)$, $y>0$. There is a fixed point $y^*$ and at this point $|f'(y^*)|<1$. Hence $y^*$ is asymptotically stable (all this follows from the mean value theorem). The second question is more complicated but the idea is that $x_n$ and $y_n$ differ by "very little".

Comment: Thanks. I will try to see if I can work out the details. In case this exchange of comments is too long, I have written a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4324896

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out the details to follow Oliver's hint and I would like to write out an answer here.

The two essential steps are proving that the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}})$ are both convergent. These two steps are nontrivial (!) and they are answered in the following two follow-up posts:

- [Convergence of a recursively defined sequence of complex numbers: $3z_{n}=z_{n-1}+z_{n-2}+z_{n-1}z_{n-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4324580/999772)
- [Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z_{n}}{z_{n-1}}$ where $3z_{n}=z_{n-1}+z_{n-2}+z_{n-1}z_{n-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4324896/999772)

It then follows by straightforward calculations that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} = \frac16(1+\sqrt{13}).
$$

Consequently, by a well-known theorem (see, e.g., Rudin's *Principle of Mathematical Analysis*) which compares the ratio and root test:
$$
\liminf _{n} \frac{\left|a_{n+1}\right|}{\left|a_{n}\right|} \leq \liminf _{n} \sqrt[n]{\left|a_{n}\right|} \leq \lim _{n} \sup \sqrt[n]{\left|a_{n}\right|} \leq \limsup _{n} \frac{\left|a_{n+1}\right|}{\left|a_{n}\right|}
$$
the desired result follows.

---

**Remark.**

It is worthing knowing that, in Python, one needs a good algorithm to calculate the $n$-th root for very big $n$. In the original attempt mentioned in the post, the total iteration number was taken too big that the plot is actually not accurate because `a**(1/n)` was used in the code to find the $n$-th root.  However, if one only iterates 100 times, one gets $b_{100}\approx 0.76759187924+\pm 10^{-11}$ which is an approximate value of $\frac{1}{6}(1+\sqrt{13})$.

[image]