# Convergence of a recursively defined sequence of complex numbers: $3z_{n}=z_{n-1}+z_{n-2}+z_{n-1}z_{n-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

**Question.**

> Let $(z_n)$ be a complex sequence such that
> $$
> z_0 = 0,\quad  z_1=1, \quad z_{n}=\frac13(z_{n-1}+z_{n-2}+z_{n-1}z_{n-2})\quad (n>1)\tag{1}
> $$
> Prove that the limit of the sequence exists.

**Observations.**

1. <s>This is a *complex* sequence; one cannot expect to apply the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) directly.</s>

   <sup>(Added notes: Thanks to paw88789's comment below, this is actually a *real* sequence. The $z_n$'s are originally coefficients of a complex power series (in the linked question mentioned later) which *could* be complex. But I overlooked the assumption that it is immediate from the definition that they are actually all real. One could generalize this problem by replacing  $z_1$ with some non-real complex number though. But that's not the current focus. Since this sequence is actually real and bounded from below, one can directly apply the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) if one can show that the sequence is "eventually" decreasing.)</sup>
2. One straightforward idea is to show that the sequence is Cauchy. However, it seems difficult to directly estimate $|z_m-z_n|$ using (1).
3. The recurrence in (1) is very close to [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients), where one can use the characteristic function techniques. But it is not very clear how to pass from "linear" to "nonlinear".

**Remarks.**

This is a follow-up question to another [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4323888/) of mine. The question above is an essential step in one approach to establish the calculation in the linked question. I find this isolated step itself is interesting. Since I figured out a detailed proof enlighted by a [sketchy comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323888/finding-limsup-n-to-infty-sqrtna-n-for-a-recursively-defined-sequence#comment9014171_4323888) under the linked post, I will post one proof as an answer below.

I would also like to see *other* approaches to the question.

Comment: Calling this a complex sequence seems a bit of a stretch, as all the terms will be pure real (imaginary part $0$); or am I missing something?

Comment: @paw88789: Aha, indeed! The $z_n$'s are original coefficients of a complex power series (in the linked question) which *could* be complex. But I overlooked the assumption that it is immediate from the recursive definition that they are actually all real. // Now one can generalize this problem by replacing  $z_1$ with some non-real complex number though.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>**Updated.** Thanks to Philipp's comment below, I realize that the "base step" is missing in the original argument; I find a way to fix it as below. The parameter $k$ is the original argument is also not needed.</sup>

**Proof**. It suffices to show that

> for sufficiently large $n$, $0\le a_n\le q^n$ for some $0<q<1$ where $a_n:=|z_n|$.

By considering the function $f(x)=3x^2-x-1$ one can find that for all $n\ge 7$, $$
q^n\le 3q^2-q-1,\quad q:=0.9\tag{3}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\frac13(q^n+q^{n-1}+q^{2n-1})\le q^{n+1}\tag{4}
$$
Let $P(m)$ be the statement that $a_m\le q^m$. We now show by induction that $P(m)$ is true for all $m\ge 7$.

Base step. $P(7)$ is true by direct calculation by hand. (One can also write a program with a short loop to do that.)

Induction step. Suppose $P(m)$ is true for all $m$ with $7\le m\le n$ ($n>7$), we show that $P(n+1)$ is true. This follows from the induction hypothesis and (4):
$$
a_{n+1}\le \frac13(|z_n|+|z_{n-1}|+|z_n|\cdot |z_{n-1}|)\le
\frac{1}{3}(q^n+q^{n-1}+q^{2n-1})\le q^{n+1}~.
$$

Q.E.D.

---

[Original proof where the base step is missing.]

It suffices to show that

> for sufficiently large $n$, $0\le a_n\le kq^n$ for some $k>0$ and $0<q<1$ where $a_n:=|z_n|$.

A straightforward induction shows that $0\le a_n< 1$ for $n\ge 2$. Indeed, in the induction step, by the triangle inequality:
$$
0\le a_{n+1}=|z_{n+1}|< \frac13(|z_n|+|z_{n-1}|+|z_nz_{n-1}|)<\frac13(1+1+1)=1\;.
$$

Now let us find a possible pair of $k$ and $q$ that works. Assume that $a_m\le kq^m$ for all $m\le n$. One must have
$$
a_{n+1}\le \frac13(|z_n|+|z_{n-1}|+|z_nz_{n-1}|)\le
\frac{k}{3}(q^n+q^{n-1}+kq^{2n-1})~.
$$
So **if**
$$
\frac{k}{3}(q^n+q^{n-1}+kq^{2n-1})\le kq^{n+1}\tag{1}
$$
then by induction $a_n\le kq^n$ for all $n$. Note that (1) is equivalent to

$$
kq^n\le 3q^2-q-1\tag{2}
$$
Consider the function $f(x)=3x^2-x-1$. Note that $f(0)=-1<0$ and $f(1)=1>0$. Hence, by the intermidiate value theorem, there exists $r\in(0,1)$ such that $f(r)=\frac12$. Let $q=r, k=1$ in (2). Then (2) is true for *all* sufficiently large $n$.

Consequently, we have $a_n\le r^n$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: The order of your arguments is a bit confusing and makes it hard to follow your idea. Let me add a few remarks. First, your *induction hypothesis*: "$x_m\leq kq^m$ for all $m\leq n$" is slightly flawed. This becomes clear if you write down the proof a bit more thoroughly. Second, we don't need $k$, instead we look for a $n_0$ and a $q$ with $0<q<1$ such that 
$$
\frac{q^n+q^{n-1}+q^{2n-1}}{3}\leq q^{n+1}\iff q^n\le 3q^2-q-1~~~~~(1)
$$ 
holds for all $n>n_0$. The existence of such $n_0$ and $q$ is clear.

Comment: Then, we try to find the base case where we would like to start the induction, i.e. some index $i$, usually $i=0$ or $i=1$. As we have already assumed $n>n_0$ our base case must have an index $i$ such that $i>n_0$. To be rigorous, one must show that $x_i\leq q^i$ for that particular $i$. Then, we assume the *induction hypothesis* "$x_n\leq q^n$" for a specific $n$ with $n>n_0+1$, combine it with $(1)$ and conclude
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+x_{n-1}+x_nx_{n-1}}{3}<\frac{q^n+q^{n-1}+q^{2n-1}}{3}\leq q^{n+1}.
$$
Hence, $x_n\leq q^n$ for all $n\geq i$.

Comment: @Philipp: Oops, the base step is indeed missing in the original argument. Thank you for the comments. I edited the proof accordingly.

Comment: There is still a little mistake. The induction hypothesis must be $a_m\le q^m$ **and** $a_{m-1}\le q^{m-1}$ because you use the indices $n$ and $n-1$ in your induction step. So you have to add the case $n+2$ to your induction step. Then, the induction hypothesis is shown for $n+1$ and $n+2$ which shows monotonicity for all $n>7$.

Comment: @Philipp: I am using the [strong version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) of induction. The induction hypothesis is (for any fixed $n>7$) "Suppose () is true for *all* $m$ with $7\le m\le n$". In particularly, $P(n)$ and $P(n-1)$ are both true.

Comment: Yes you are right, please ignore my last comment, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Although ripples answer is pretty clever, I would like add another one where we use the monotone convergence theorem of real sequences.

---

The boundedness is clear. Then we do a short proof by induction to show monotonicity.

The base case/the induction starts at the index $6$ as $z_6-z_5<0$ and $z_6-z_4<0$.

Then, we assume the induction hypothesis "$z_{n}<z_{n-1}$ and $z_n<z_{n-2}$ with $n>5$".

The induction step $n\to n+1$ can be shown as follows:

$$
z_{n+1}-z_n=\frac{z_{n}+z_{n-1}+z_{n}z_{n-1}}{3}-\frac{z_{n-1}+z_{n-2}+z_{n-1}z_{n-2}}{3}\\=\frac{z_n-z_{n-2}+z_{n-1}(z_n-z_{n-2})}{3}=\frac{(1+z_{n-1})(z_n-z_{n-2})}{3}\underset{\text{hypothesis}}{\underset{\text{induction}}{<}}0
$$
and
$$
z_{n+1}-z_{n-1}<z_{n+1}-z_n\underset{\text{above}}{\underset{\text{see}}{<}}0.
$$
Hence, the real valued sequence $(z_n)$ is monotone from the $5$-th member onward. Due to monotone convergence theorem the sequence is convergent.